# Save 2-D gaussian_kde output/meshgrid to csv python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am very new to python (with pure .net background) I am using [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) tutorial to generate 2-d kde analysis.

Generate some random two-dimensional data:

```
from scipy import stats
def measure(n):
    "Measurement model, return two coupled measurements."
    m1 = np.random.normal(size=n)
    m2 = np.random.normal(scale=0.5, size=n)
    return m1+m2, m1-m2
m1, m2 = measure(2000)
xmin = m1.min()
xmax = m1.max()
ymin = m2.min()
ymax = m2.max()
```

Perform a kernel density estimate on the data:

```
X, Y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]
positions = np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([m1, m2])
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values)
Z = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, X.shape)
```

Plot the results:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(np.rot90(Z), cmap=plt.cm.gist_earth_r,
          extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
ax.plot(m1, m2, 'k.', markersize=2)
ax.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
plt.show()
```

I need its output to a csv or other parse-able format so that I can render it on .net application. I looked at pmeshcolor method it can generate svg but that becomes very huge for large data set.

I need something like following so that I can further filter it on .net application

Input:

```
x1 y1  
x2 y2  
x3 y3
```

... (or it could be comma separated, basically I will be extracting this from shape file or fetching from database directly, my major concern is on output)

Expected output

```
x1 y1 value_from_kde  
x2 y2 value_from_kde  
x3 y3 value_from_kde
```

... where value_from_kde is output from gaussian_kde function for that specific point, I understand that gaussian_kde uses a grid to perform this analysis and its output is also grid if this point to point value is not possible, a rectangle with its associated value is also acceptable like

rectangle coordinate [p1 p2 p3 p4] value_from_kde

output shall not have records where value_from_kde is zero.

Note: It is important to keep the rectangle coordinates in same formate as it was input so that i can be rendered with the same projection like I am using x,y to input for kde in UTM format that looks like this 671290.9984 2727340.004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to simply output the resulting x,y,value to a file for later processing (omitting zero values).  If so you might want to not reshape Z for simplifying the output process (that is my Z1)

```
fid = open('output.csv','w')
Z1 = (kernel(positions).T, X.shape)
Z = kernel(positions).T
#for currentIndex,elem in enumerate(positions):
for currentIndex,elem in enumerate(Z):
  #if Z1[currentIneex]>0:
  s1 = '%f %f %f\n'%(positions[0][currentIndex], positions[1][currentIndex], Z[currentIndex] )

  fid.write(s1)
fid.close()
```

Am I missing something to your question?

Comment: if Z[currentIndex]>0:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: If I remove the if statement there is still error  

s1 = '%f %f %f\n'%(elem[0],elem[1],Z[currentIndex])'
'TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.ndarray

Comment: You summarized my problem correctly (Simply output to x,y,value where value > 0)

Comment: @Asad, one very important point.  I have a variable defined called Z1.  It is different than Z.  Your comment says Z[currentIndex]>0    That will not work as Z is a matrix.  You need to first defnie Z1 - it is the same thing as Z but it is not reshaped to a matrix.  Z1 = (kernel(positions).T, X.shape)   and  Z = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, X.shape).  My code uses Z1 as it is a 1D vector and still has elements ordered properly.

Comment: I am aware of it. I changed the Z = (kernel(positions).T, X.shape). I believe it still does reshape the array, as you are providing X.shape as second part [may becomes a tuple, I dont know much python notations].

Comment: Thanks to pointing me in right direction, I was able to get the desired results with some changes in your provided code. I am posting working code here, Please make it part of your answer. So that others can find it.

Comment: Z = kernel(positions).T
for currentIndex,elem in enumerate(Z):
    print positions[0][currentIndex],positions[1][currentIndex],Z[currentIndex]

Comment: And If we need rectangle (bbox) with value  [minx,maxx,miny,maxy,value]  following code works

mshgrd = ax.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z)
pths = mshgrd.get_paths()
arr = mshgrd.get_array()

for currentIndex,elem in enumerate(pths):
  if arr[currentIndex]>0:
    bbox = elem.get_extents()
    s2 = ",".join([str(i) for i in bbox.extents])+","+ str(arr[currentIndex]) +'\n'
    print s2

Comment: I made your changes from Z=kernel...    Glad that you got it working.