# Same resultset imshow can plot while pcolormesh cannot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, kernel-density

I am using scipy.stats.kde.gaussian_kde() for kde analysis, It takes time to process large number of point (for 100000 points with 250x250 grid it is taking 5 minutes).

As an faster alternative to gaussian_kde I found fast_kde function [here](http://pastebin.com/LNdYCZgw) written by [Joe Kington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325565/joe-kington). (weighted kde was also a factor to choose fast_kde)

Rather plotting the result, I extract it to file in format (xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,value) for later use. I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19700982/save-2-d-gaussian-kde-output-meshgrid-to-csv-python) technique to extract the results in raw form by using [pcolormesh](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh).

**Here is the problem statement:**
results produced by fast_kde function for grid (500,500) are not plot-able by pcolormesh and output in raw form is also reflecting same invalid results, however imshow method plots this result prefectly.

Generate some random two-dimensional data:

```
from scipy import stats
def measure(n):
    "Measurement model, return two coupled measurements."
    m1 = np.random.normal(size=n)
    m2 = np.random.normal(scale=0.5, size=n)
    return m1+m2, m1-m2
m1, m2 = measure(2000)
xmin = m1.min()
xmax = m1.max()
ymin = m2.min()
ymax = m2.max()
```

Perform a kernel density estimate on the data:

```
X, Y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]
positions = np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([m1, m2])
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values)
Z = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, X.shape)
```

Save results to file:  (x,y,value)

```
fid = open('output.csv','w')
Z1 = (kernel(positions).T, X.shape)
Z = kernel(positions).T
#for currentIndex,elem in enumerate(positions):
for currentIndex,elem in enumerate(Z):
  #if Z1[currentIneex]>0:
  s1 = '%f %f %f\n'%(positions[0][currentIndex], positions[1][currentIndex], Z[currentIndex] )
  fid.write(s1)
fid.close()
```

Print results:  (minx,maxx,miny,maxy,value)

```
mshgrd = ax.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z) 
pths = mshgrd.get_paths() 
arr = mshgrd.get_array() 
for currentIndex,elem in enumerate(pths): 
 if arr[currentIndex]>0: bbox = elem.get_extents() 
 s2 = ",".join([str(i) for i in bbox.extents])+","+ str(arr[currentIndex]) +'\n' 
 print s2
```

Plot the results:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(np.rot90(Z), cmap=plt.cm.gist_earth_r,
          extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
ax.plot(m1, m2, 'k.', markersize=2)
ax.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
plt.show()
```

Code using for fast_kde (**problem area**)

```
kernel = fast_kde(m1,m2,(500,500))
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
mshgrd = ax.pcolormesh(X,Y,kernel)
plt.show()
```

**Please suggest me how to add images here (where to upload?)**

Comment: please post some example code.

Comment: It is mentioned is question. I am using [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19700982/save-2-d-gaussian-kde-output-meshgrid-to-csv-python), for clarity I am adding it to question.

Comment: Can you cut this down to the bare-minimum needed to demonstrate your problem?  and any photo-sharing site will work (google, imgur, ect)